# How to make my selenium script run forever on heroku

Tags: python, selenium, heroku

I have created an selenium bot that posts every 20 minutes on Instagram
I deployed my project to heroku and everything but i don't know how to make it run forever
I tried `heroku run python mycode.py` in the command promt but the program would stop working if i close command prompt

Answer (score 1):

`heroku run` is for ad hoc interactive stuff.

For a long-running background process you should define a worker process in your `Procfile`:

```
worker: python mycode.py
```

Commit that change and redeploy. Then scale up a dyno to run it:

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

This will either consume free dyno hours or, if you are using paid dynos, incur costs.